# Is there a modern alternative to redmon redirected port?

Tags: printing, redmon

I am trying to create a "virtual" printer which should use Redmon port (or an alternative) to redirect the printed document to an application.

I used to follow that old guide to try that :

- https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi32frjqIHrAhWGmBQKHStoCsQQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp-developpez.com%2Ffarscape%2Ftutoriels%2FGhostPdfWriter.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3RobF7Gculr_hAyVho9PLO

But on the page 10 when I try to apply the new redirected port on the printer, windows show me a 'fabulous' error message which say :

```
Printer settings could not be saved.

Operation not supported.
```

(I tried that with administrator privileges)

So my question is, is there a 'simple' way to achieve that, or an alternative to Redmon that will work on windows 10 ?

Thank you for your attention and for your help !